# Delete rows, which are duplicated and follow each other consequently

Tags: sql, vertica

It's hard to formulate, so i'll just show an example and you are welcome to edit my question and title.

Suppose, i have a table

```
   flag id  value datetime
0   b   1   343   13
1   a   1   23    12 
2   b   1   21    11
3   b   1   32    10
4   c   2   43    11
5   d   2   43    10
6   d   2   32     9
7   c   2   1      8
```

For **each** `id` i want to squeze the table by `flag` columns such that all duplicate `flag` values that follow each other collapse to one row with `sum` aggregation. **Desired result**:

```
   flag id  value
0   b   1   343
1   a   1   23
2   b   1   53
3   c   2   75
4   d   2   32
5   c   2   1
```

**P.S:** I found functions like `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT`, which seem to be able to do that, but the examples of them in docs dont work for me

Comment: is there a column to specify the order?

Comment: @lad2025 The same logic - they must collapse in one

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Unfortunatly, not. And i'm not able to add it. But i have a `date` column, which is practicly the same

Comment: then you can't get what you're trying to do, reliably..in my opinion.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I have edited the question( added a new column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the differnece of row number approach to assign groups based on consecutive row flags being the same. Thereafter use a running sum.

```
select distinct id,flag,sum(value) over(partition by id,grp) as finalvalue
from (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by id order by datetime)-row_number() over(partition by id,flag order by datetime) as grp
from tbl t
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which uses CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT:

```
select
    flag,
    id,
    sum(value) value
from (
    select
        conditional_change_event(flag) over (order by datetime desc) part,
        flag,
        id,
        value
    from so
) t
group by part, flag, id
order by part;
```

The result is different from your desired result stated in the question because of `order by datetime`. Adding a separate column for the row number and sorting on that gives the correct result.